# Can I play xesc file on Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4

It seems very weird and I can't understand it,

Why xesc, the output of Expression Encoder 4 Screen Capture, can't be play on Silverlight??

Why ScreenCaptureVideoProfile codec is always unknown?

doesn't the left hand know what the right hand is doing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Microsoft Expression Encoder team

> Being optimized for screen capture, the XESC codec has dependencies
>   that are platform dependant and thus doesn't really fit in the
>   Silverlight model.

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/12115880-e529-477f-a44d-2577e30770ac/