# What are the limitations of each VC1 profile?

Tags: codec, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4, vc1

When I'm trying to a conversion with the following parameters:

```
mediaItem.OutputFormat.VideoProfile = new MainVC1VideoProfile()
                    {
                        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1200),
                        Bitrate = new VariableQualityBitrate(75),
                        Complexity = VideoComplexity.Normal,
                        FrameRate = 1,
                        KeyFrameDistance = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
                    };
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The combined width, height and frame rate are too high for this
>   profile.

Can anyone help me and tell me what are the limitations to each profile?

SimpleVC1VideoProfile
MainVC1VideoProfile
AdvancedVC1VideoProfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC1's Main profile can support a maximum resolution of up to 1920 x 1080.
In your code, you are setting the resolution to 1920 x 1200, hence with a width greater to the maximum allowed.

Simple profile supports up to CIF resolution (352 x 288) and Advanced profile can decode up to 2048 x 1536 (but with a bite rate = 135 MBits/s).

It looks to me like your best bet is to resize the source to 1920 x 1080.

For more information, check [this Microsoft article](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/vc1techoverview.aspx) or [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC-1#Profiles).

Comment: Thanks! is there any chance you know the answer to my second question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446580/can-i-play-xesc-file-on-silverlight